# Ninject cannot find and bind to the repository correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

This is so frustrating and has stopped me from continuing reading `ASP.NET MVC` because the rest of topic are building upon this one: I am following `Adam Freeman's book Pro ASP.NET MVC 5.0` book which I am sure many of you have also studied it. So I am done with Chapter 7 and this doesn't work. I can bring up the site but there are no products showing on the right side of the page.

As far as I could debug here is what I found:
`ProductController` returns no products, which I think it is because `Ninject` isn't working correctly
https://github.com/babakinks/MVCExample/blob/master/SportsStore/SportsStore.WebUI/Controllers/ProductController.cs

```
public class ProductController : Controller

{
    private IProductsRepository repository;
    public int PageSize = 4;

    public ProductController(IProductsRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
    {
        ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel
        {
            Products = repository.Products
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = repository.Products.Count()
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And I don't think it is because I don't have enough data in my DB, because I can query them.

**Only thing:** I had to add this method in the `Global.asax.cs`

```
 private void RegisterDependencyResolver()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        // you may need to configure your container here?
        //RegisterServices(kernel);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
    }
```

If I don't, I will get a `parameter-less constructor error` for `ProductsController`

If you want to take a look, here is the whole thing:
https://github.com/babakinks/MVCExample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninject's task in this piece of code is finding an instance of `IProductsRepository` and creating a new `ProductController` instance with this repository.

1. Your `NinjectDependencyResolver` contains `kernel.Bind<IProductsRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();`. So you have bound the service interface to the entity framework implementation.
2. Your `ProductController` is dependent on an `IProductsRepository` instance. It won't create one without a repository.
3. If Ninject somehow couldn't resolve a repository instance, you'd get an `ActivationException` with detailed error information. I assume you don't get this error.
4. If Ninject would inject `null` (which it doesn't by default and which is not recommended), you would get a `NullReferenceException` in your `List` method, which I assume you don't get either.
5. So obviously, everything works as expected and Ninject is injecting a repository instance. Skip and Take also looks good.

I downloaded your project, added some items to the products table in the mdf database file in App_Data and it worked instantly. You have a debugging problem over there.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to test the application. Could you please explain a little more about this: " You have a debugging problem over there."

Comment: @Blake: Well, I cloned your git project, built it, put some rows in the database and it worked. Are you sure that you have data in there? Keep in mind that ASP.net is using the files in the App_Data folder.